# how can i download my data from google-cloud-platform using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, google-cloud-platform, pycharm

I have my data on google cloud platform and i want to be able to be able to download it locally, this is my first time trying that and eventually i'll use the downloaded data with my python code.

I have checked the docs, like https://cloud.google.com/genomics/downloading-credentials-for-api-access and https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console i have successfully got the Json file for my first link, the second one is where u'm struggling, i'm using python 3.5 and assuming my json files name is `data.json` i have added the following code:

```
os.environ["file"] = "data.json"
urllib.request.urlopen('https://storage.googleapis.com/[bucket_name]/[filename]')
```

first of all i don't even know what i should call the value near environ so i just called it file, not sure how i'm supposed to fill it and i got access denied on the second line, obviously it's not how to download my file as there is no destination local repository or anything in that command any guidance will be appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
   from google.cloud.storage import Blob

    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "credentials/client_secret.json"
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('service_account.json')
    client = storage.Client(project='my-project')
    bucket = client.get_bucket('my-bucket')
    blob = Blob('path/to/my-object', bucket)
    download_to_filename('local/path/to/my-file')
```

I'm getting unresolved reference for `storage` and `download_to_filename` and should i replace `service_account.json` with `credentials/client_secret.json`. Plus i tried to print the content of `os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]['installed']` like i'd do with any Json but it just said i should give numbers meaning it read the input path as regular text only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [idiomatic Google Cloud library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/client.html) to run operations in GCS.

With the example there, and knowing that the client library will get the application default credentials, first we have to set the applicaiton default credentials with

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

**===EDIT===**

That was the old way. Now you should use the instructions in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production).

This means downloading a service account key file from the [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project), and setting the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the path of the downloaded JSON.

Also, make sure that this service account has the [proper permissions](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam) on the project of the bucket.

Or you can create the client with explicit credentials. You'll need to download the key file all the same, but when creating the client, use:

```
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('service_account.json')
```

***==========***

And then, following the example code:

```
from  google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client(project='project-id')
bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket-id')
blob = storage.Blob('bucket/file/path', bucket)
blob.download_to_filename('/path/to/local/save')
```

Or, if this is a one-off download, just install the [SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/) and use `gsutil` to download:

```
gsutil cp gs://bucket/file .
```

Comment: i've read the instructions repeatedly and carefully but i still don't understand how to get the first step `gcloud auth application-default login ` done further more detailed guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer but i still haven't successfully done it, i'll edit my question to showcase where i'm at now.

Comment: Where are you running your script from? Depending on where are you running it from, there could be different causes for that.

Comment: Pycharm plus it could be really helpful if you could check all my issues in the edited question above.

Comment: It looks I forgot how to python. I just fixed the code, and I've verified this works on different linux machines, both cloud-based and local. If the corrections do not work (although for the errors you describe, it looks like the corrections should fix this), then it's something specific to pycharm.

Comment: There is no option to [download a folder](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics#download) in the API. You'll have to list the objects on the folder and download them one by one. If you run `gsutil -DD cp gs://bucket/folder/* .` you'll see that this is exactly what the CLI does.